# How to insert multiple data through raw string in sqlalchemy 2.0?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Now I'm doing it via loop and execute. Am I doing it right?  Or is there a faster way.

```
with get_db() as db:
    result = [
        {"user_id": "1","device_uid": "s1","fix": ["f1","f2"]},
        {"user_id": "2","device_uid": "s2","fix": ["f1"]}
    ]
    for i in result:
        db.execute(text(
            "INSERT INTO fix_app (user_id, device_uid,fix) VALUES (:user_id, :device_uid, :fix)"),
            i)
```